# How to store one variable in a cache inside one controller method and access it in another method in the same controller? - Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-cache

In my application, I am trying to save user information in a cache variable and access it in another method. I can access it inside the same method. But when I try to access out of that method, it returns null. I need to know how to achieve this, please someone help me out here with an example as I am new to the technology.

Inside a method:

```
Cache::set('user', $user);
```

Accessing it in another method:

```
$user = Cache::get('user');
```

And I want to clear it once accessing it.

Comment: use a class scope or singleton pattern for such problems. Cache is a completely different thing than what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Cache for storing variable.

You can declare variable in class as following

```
class test{
    public $user = []; //declare your function here.

    function abc(){
        $this->user = $user; //Assign value to variable
    }

    function xyz(){
        $user = $this->user; 
        print_r($user);
    }

}
```